# Assigning to rValue

Tags: javascript, arrays, constants, reduce

Getting an error message on this reduce function

Had this at first

```
const populationTotal = 0;
let populationTotal = zooAnimals.reduce((populationTotal, populationAmount) => {
  return populationTotal + populationAmount.population;
}, 0);

console.log(populationTotal);
```

Trying this now

```
const populationTotal = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const reducer = (populationTotal, 10) => populationTotal +

console.log(populationTotal.reduce(reducer));
```

Getting an error of SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue (190:34)

Comment: first error : that I get is Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'populationTotal' has already been declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You define `populationTotal` as `const` then try to define it again and set a value to it. That is not how [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) works. You can only set value to const at the line where you define it.
2. [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works with an `accumulator`, `current value`, `index` and `array` parameters but it is mainly used with the first two. It also accepts a default value for the accumulator as its last parameter:

The reducer function takes four arguments:

- Accumulator (acc)
- Current Value (cur)
- Current Index (idx)
- Source Array (src)

```js
let data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

// Used all four parameters but they are not needed specifically in this case, Just for illustration purposes
let result = data.reduce((acc, cur, idx, src) => acc + cur, 0)

console.log(result)
```

If you would like to define the reducer outside as a separate function you could as well:

```js
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const reducer = (acc, curr) => acc + curr

console.log(data.reduce(reducer, 0));
```